# How to enable bash for ChrootDirectory users (ssh_config)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have added on the end of file "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"

```
Match Group ftpusers
  ChrootDirectory /home/ftpusers/
  PermitTunnel no
  AllowAgentForwarding no
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

What I'm trying to do? I have restricted users in that group to access only to that directory and that works when users are using sftp but it is not working when they are using ssh connection.

While they are trying to connect they get this error:

```
/bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

That is probably because I have added ChrootDirectory to ssh config for that group.

Is there another way to let them use bash and keep ChrootDirectory in ssh config?

I have tried to mount --bind /bin folder to /home/usersftp and then change bash path in /etc/passwd for users in that group but error is still occurring.

OS: Ubuntu server 16.04

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You should read up on what a chroot is. The command `chroot` changes the root directory `/` to another directory. So if you set the chroot for a user to `/home/usersftp` and you want them to be able to open bash, then bash needs to be at `/home/usersftp/bin/bash`.

As for your question:

> Is there another way to let them use bash and keep ChrootDirectory in ssh config?

Sure, but you need to build a proper chroot environment. Explaining this here is a bit out of scope and there are countless exampless on the internet and I'm sure there are some on serverfault.

But as a starting point, you can build a chroot with package `debootstrap`.

Comment: I think there is no need for debootstrap but thank you for suggestion. I need to restrict users in that group to one directory but to enable ssh connection and with that using bash.

Answer (score 0):

The bind mount may actually work, but you need to use the new path for the login shell, which may be `/bin/bash`, when you bound `/bin/` to `/home/usersftp/bin/`.

On the other hand, you may use a restrictive shell instead of a chroot, like rssh, if you want to use the account only for filetransfers.

Comment: I want to use account only for ssh connection and using git command in chroot directory.

Comment: Have a look at tools, which manage this for you, like gitosis. I am not sure if it is using a chroot, but it is definitely restricting the account to only using git.

Comment: But I want for user to use  basic console commands + git but to stay only in chroot directory.

Comment: bind mount is not working :(

Comment: a bind mount before the chroot call should work (but do not forget to mount /lib as well). Another option may be to use some overlayfs, but this is much complexity for what you want to achive. There are more choices without chroot (rssh, rush, ...) or you put the needed binaries inside the chroot. There are a lot of script to scan your binaries for the minimum of needed depencies to put into the jail, like ``makejail``

Comment: /lib and /lib64 were missing also in chroot. now mount bind has solved the issue.